# Can I use category and runtime to add a BOOL type property "isScrolling" to UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, runtime, categories

I used to add a `NSString *`type property to `UIButton`,today however,I want to add a `BOOL` type property `isScrolling` to `UIScrollView` to indicate whether the scrollView is scrolling in the same way but there showed something wrong,here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIScrollView (Util)

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isScrolling;

@end




#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>

@interface UIScrollView ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation UIScrollView (Util)

static void *strKey = &strKey;

- (void)setIsScrolling:(BOOL)isScrolling{ 
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, & strKey, isScrolling,    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (BOOL)isScrolling{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &strKey);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    self.isScrolling = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    self.isScrolling = NO;
}

@end
```

And the error is:
[image]

Is there any way to deal with thses errors and can we use category and runtime to achieve the goal of adding a `BOOL` property to `UIScrollView` to indicate whether the scrollView is scrolling?

Hope someone can give me some advice,thanks a lot.

Comment: post code as it is. Please don't screenshot it.

Comment: objc_getAssociatedObject is for Object Type. BOOL is not Object type. Thats why you got the error

Comment: @LalKrishna Yeah,I had edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the error is showing implicit conversion of BOOL to id, you need to send a object instead of primitive types.

The method signature for objc_setAssociatedObject is

```
/** 
 * Sets an associated value for a given object using a given key and association policy.
 * 
 * @param object The source object for the association.
 * @param key The key for the association.
 * @param value The value to associate with the key key for object. Pass nil to clear an existing association.
 * @param policy The policy for the association. For possible values, see “Associative Object Behaviors.”
 * 
 * @see objc_setAssociatedObject
 * @see objc_removeAssociatedObjects
 */

OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
    OBJC_AVAILABLE(10.6, 3.1, 9.0, 1.0);
```

Above you can see the value should be object.

Change your code 
`@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isScrolling;` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *scrolling;`

And change `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` to `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` in your case `objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &strkey, scrolling, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);`

And use `[_scrolling boolValue]` for checking.

Comment: Yes,you are right.But can we handle the UIScrollView delegate in category so that we can set the value to 'scrolling' property.I had tried just now and it is invalid.Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can override delegate methods in category. I can try helping you post your code.

Answer (score 1):

An *associated object* must be just that, an object, and so a value of the non-object `BOOL` type won't work unless wrapped as an object. Fortunately that is pretty easy:

- In the call to `objc_setAssociatedObject` change `isScrolling` to `@(isScrolling)` and change `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` to `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`. This will create and pass an `NSNumber` object, the second change requesting that this object's lifetime be tied to that of the first parameter, `self`.
- In `isScrolling` change `objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &strKey)` to `[objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &strKey) boolValue]`. This will extract the `BOOL` value from the stored `NSNumber` object.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Try to convert boolean to nsnumber.

```
  -(void)setIsScrolling:(BOOL)isScrolling{
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, & strkey), [NSNumber numberWithBool:isScrolling], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the primitive data type as an `AssociatedObject`, It's an Object. Convert `bool` to `NSNumber` when you are saving the data. Convert `NSNumber` to `bool` while reading the data.

**`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN`** - Specifies a weak reference to the associated object.
**`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`** - Specifies a strong reference to the associated object, and that the association is not made atomically.

**.h File :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIScrollView (ScrollViewCategory)

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSNumber *isScrolling;

@end
```

**.m File**

```
@interface UIScrollView ()

@end

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIScrollView (ScrollViewCategory)

@dynamic isScrolling;

- (void)setAssociatedObject:(id)object {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject), object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)associatedObject {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject));
}
```